# Swift SnapKit dynamic height issue

Tags: swift, constraints, snapkit

i have used snapKit on **DispatchQueue.main.async** to set constraints programmatically. But i noticed that **main.async** sometimes causes freeze UI and i change method to use it. Now i have problem to use dynamic height, old method cause error when i try to make dynamic height depends of content...

**OLD METHOD** (innerView - is subview of view)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(45)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(12)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.innerView.snp.bottom).offset(12)
        })
    }
//After i add it like superView.addSubView(view)
//superView contains view, and view(dynamic height) contains innerView
```

**NEW METHOD**

```
superView.addSubview(view)
view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(45)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(12)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.innerView.snp.bottom).offset(12)
        })
```

[image]

Comment: what error / crash ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan its SnapKit relation error..

Comment: can you post it

Comment: @Sh_Khan i don't know if its possible to make bottom constraint when you don't really know subView constraints. Yes... async it will work, but this way. Don't know if it possible

Comment: Does `innerView` inside `superView` also ?

Comment: superView its main View of UIViewController
superView contains view (its container of login fields)
innerView its login field class

Comment: @Sh_Khan basically superView cover all visible view /  
superView.addSubVeiw(view)
view.addSubview(innerView)

Comment: do you add it before setting the constraints

Comment: yes, i do addSubview(view), then i add constraints (NEW), before was in async, constraints, then addSubview(view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue, just in case someone will need it... add  make.bottom.equalTo(self.innerView.snp.bottom).offset(12), after you add all superview constraints and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both before setting the constraints

```
superView.addSubview(view)
superView.addSubview(innerView) //  or view.addSubview(innerView) if it's nested UI
view.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
     make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(45)
     make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(12)
     make.bottom.equalTo(self.innerView.snp.bottom).offset(12)
})
```